# Sometime RenderScript can't detect all CPUs in my phone

Tags: android, renderscript

Each time create a script, this log will appear:

```
03-28 16:13:19.280: V/RenderScript_jni(12226): RS compat mode
03-28 16:13:19.280: V/RenderScript(12226): 0x292b20 Launching thread(s), CPUs 2
```

But sometimes the second line won't appear, and my program run slower than normal time. Here are some log of processing time:

```
03-28 16:54:11.220: V/RenderScript_jni(12226): RS compat mode
03-28 16:54:11.220: V/RenderScript(12226): 0x2c5708 Launching thread(s), CPUs 2
03-28 16:54:18.140: I/MainActivity(12226): 263 ms
// When RenderScript detected all CPUs in my phone, it took 263ms to apply a curve on one 1MP image.

03-28 16:53:14.065: V/RenderScript_jni(12226): RS compat mode
03-28 16:53:21.185: I/MainActivity(12226): 454 ms
//But most time it can't detect another CPU, so it took twice time to process the same image
```

I know I should post some related data about my device and android sdk/tools version:
My device: SAMSUNG I9100 (has 2 CPUs, GPU is Mali-400MP, so rs can't use GPU to accelerate)
Android version: 4.0.3 (rs can only use compat mode)
SDK buildtools: 19.0.3

In my program, my script contains more than 30 kernels, now it is hard for rs to detect all CPUs in my phone. But I create another project with a script that only has 4 kernels, testing shows that most of time rs can find all the CPUs. It is weird!

Is it a bug or should I set some parameters to tell rs my phone actually has 2 CPUs!?

Comment: By the way, I was banned to answer question. When I got it, I have already typed more than 60 lines answer, this make me angry. Why can't this website tell me I was banned to answer when I typed first letter? Anything else, RenderScript is not popular like OpenGLES, so there are only a little programers use it. In other words, questions about RS have less even have no possibility to be voted up. How can I get out of it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug though I'm not sure if its in the compat lib or device.

Can you add the contents of /proc/cpuinfo ?  Either we are parsing something in it wrong or its changing dynamically which sometimes happens due to power management.

Comment: Processor  : ARMv7 Processor rev 1 (v7l)
processor  : 0
BogoMIPS  : 1592.52
processor  : 1
BogoMIPS  : 1990.65
Features   : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls 
CPU implementer  : 0x41
CPU architecture : 7
CPU variant  : 0x2
CPU part  : 0xc09
CPU revision  : 1
Hardware  : SMDK4210
Revision   : 000e
Serial   : 304d09aa4b10222f

Comment: Maybe you should consider this, when my app starts running, it creates the first script in MainActivity, and rs can detect all 2 CPUs in most of time. But when I click a button, make app jump to another Activity(create the second script without releasing of the first), normally rs can't find the second CPU. When this happened, I have to quit back to MainActivity and re-enter the second Activity to make my app rebuild the second script. Repeat many times(10+ times normally), rs will finally find the second CPU.

Comment: In one word, it seems that rs has a great possibility to find all CPUs when it creates the first script, not for the second.